# decodeUri not working with res.json express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Have an express app that saves a sanitized url to a mongodb database and I want to render the decoded url in a res.json using decodeURI() but it doesn't work as expected and only gives the encoded version back. If I do a res.send(decodeURI(url)) it works. How can I get the res.json to send the decoded url.

```
        // Create a url object with escaped and trimmed data.
    var Url = new UrlModel(
      { url: req.body.url }
    );


    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        // There are errors. Render the form again with error messages.
        res.render('index', { errors: errors.array()});
    return;
    }
    else {
        // Data from form is valid.
        // Check if Url with same name already exists.
        UrlModel.findOne({ 'url': req.body.url })
            .exec( function(err, found_url) {
                 if (err) { return next(err); }

                 if (found_url) {
                     // Url exists, redirect to its detail page.
                     res.json({"original_url": decodeURI(found_url.url) });
                     //res.send(decodeURI(found_url.url))

                 }
```

---

**Update:**

Probably wasn't clear in my question. My input is from a mongodb with a sanitized  url in the form

```
https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.facebook.com
```

so its html entities that i want to convert and I dont think that decodeUri does that.
My out put from this code

`res.json({original_url:found_url.url, decoded: decodeURI(found_url.url) });`

is `{"original_url":"https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.facebook.com","decoded":"https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.facebook.com"}`

so the `&#x2F;&#x2F;` in the url is not being converted to // . Is there some core javascript function that does this or do I have to use a function with regx and replace?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated after question update.**

In JavaScript you have some functions to accomplish a similar conversion: `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`, and their counterparts `decodeURI` and `decodeURIComponent`. `encodeURI` is used to safely encode a full URL as it won't encode the protocol, hostname or the path; `encodeURIComponent` will encode everything.

What you are showing in the edited question has nothing (as far as I can tell) to do with JavaScript; you need to get the backend to unsanitize that string before sending it back to you.

If updating the backend is not an option, you could try something like this:

```
unescape('https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.facebook.com'.replace(/&#x/g, '%').replace(/;/g, ''))
```

This will decode those entities into their actual characters, but it should not be a permanent solution as it is [marked as deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape).

---

**Original response.**

I am having no issues at all with encodeURI and decodeURI. Are you completely sure it is not being returned as expected? Is there a chance something else in the middle is encoding it again?

I tested this small snippet with Postman.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const encoded = encodeURI('http://example.com?query=ÅÍÎÏ˝ÓÔÒÚÆ☃');
const decoded = decodeURI(encoded);

app.get('/json', (req, res) => res.json({ encoded, decoded }));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

[image: postman screencapture]

Comment: Thanks edited my question above to add some more info. It's html entities I need to convert.

Comment: Updated response to match your question. TL;DR use `unescape` + `replace` as a workaround, but get that updated on your backend.